Windows 10 getting Device Freeze message
Something terrible has happened to my laptop. The first screen that comes on says, device freeze. It's a white screen and it won't let me go any farther, about asset Management, device reported as missing stolen something. Gives an email for them so that I can give them my address so they can send me a FedEx box to return the laptop. Had this laptop for I several years.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

What exactly is your question? Someone at the company who owned or owns the company reported the device as stolen. At no point did you wipe the device?

Yes ,somebody claims the laptop was stolen and yes it was wiped by the time I bought it on eBay.

@VivianMadoda - If the previous owner of the device reported it stolen, and that owner is not whom you purchased it from, then you have no real recourse or a way forward.

You bought it from a thief or scammer. While some commenters note wiping the device may allow you to use it again, the anti-theft measures may be operating at the device firmware level and so wiping the OS wouldn't solve the problem, or they may be tied to device identifiers that are difficult to obfuscate or change, and so the next time you connect to the internet after you wipe the device, it'll probably have the same result.
Your solution has two steps:

Contact the organization that has reported the laptop stolen and explain your situation. Having a copy of the eBay transaction receipt will probably help. If you're lucky they can lift the lock and release the device. But they may also have regulatory security requirements and you may not be allowed to keep the device. That is up to them because they are the actual owners, even if you paid real money for the laptop.

Report the seller on eBay.



Author didn't really specify the OEM of the hardware, so I didn't consider, the firmware features might be the root cause.

I've never seen LoJack activated on a computer, but I've seen the branding on plenty of business-line computers I've worked with. I suppose there are some orgs that actually pay for it, even if I've never met one.

Wouldn't LoJack be a software solution that would have been wiped when the system was Reset? This seems more of a Dell/HP enterprise level firmware capability.

I thought LoJack offered a licensed firmware product at one time. But yea, it seems this screen is specific to Computrace, which is Dell's product.

It turns out that, Absolute Home & Office , formally known as Computrace was formally called LoJack. Computrace once activated, cannot be deactivated, so if it's been activated on the device it explains the behavior the author describes.

Hah! My memory wasn't so bad as I though! :)
